# Send to multiple RabbitMQ hosts with MassTransit

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq, masstransit

I'm using MassTransit in .NET application with RabbitMQ. It works as it should, I have configured and registered MassTransit bus control in ioc and now I can send messages to my RabbitMQ instance and consume them.

Now I need to have possibility to send message to another instance of RabbitMQ. How do I do this? I don't need to consume messages from this other RabbitMQ, I only need to send there something.

I tried to inject ISendEndpointProvider and use GetSendEndpoint with URI of my other RabbitMQ instance but that does not seems to work. I don't have any errors but my other RabbitMQ doesn't get any messages when I try to send them that way. MassTransit documentation doesn't say anything about connecting to multiple hosts.

Thanks for all suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UPDATE: As of v7, MassTransit includes support for [multiple bus instances](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/containers/multibus.html).

Comment: Thank you. Can I run into some issues if I create new bus control for my other-rabbit, start it and put into some singleton object that will be registered in ioc container? I need to send stuff with that bus quite often so I'm not sure if starting/stopping each time would be efficient. On the other hand if I register my singleton with started bus control then I'm probably going to miss some of the MassTransit connection management features, am I correct?

Comment: You can register some other type of object in the container, and have it hold the reference to the IBusControl, make sure it's disposable, and it can start the bus for you. Once the container is disposed, you can stop the bus on dispose. It's best to leave it connected and in the container, it just can't be the same interface type of IBusControl.